# Why does XML::LibXML find no nodes for this xpath query when using a namespace

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, libxml2

I'm attempting to select a node using an XPath query and I don't understand why XML::LibXML doesn't find the node when it has an xmlns atribute.  Here's a script to demonstrate the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::LibXML; # 1.70 on libxml2 from libxml2-dev 2.6.16-7sarge1 (don't ask)
use XML::XPath;  # 1.13
use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.8.4; # don't ask

my ($xpath, $libxml, $use_namespace) = @ARGV;

my $xml = sprintf(<<'END_XML', ($use_namespace ? 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"' : q{}));
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<RootElement>
  <MyContainer %s>
    <MyField>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </MyField>
    <MyField>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>Ben</Value>
    </MyField>
  </MyContainer>
</RootElement>
END_XML

my $xml_parser
    = $libxml ? XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml, keep_blanks => 1)
    :           XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);

my $nodecount = 0;
foreach my $node ($xml_parser->findnodes($xpath)) {
    $nodecount ++;
    print "--NODE $nodecount--\n"; #would use say on newer perl
    print $node->toString($libxml && 1), "\n";
}

unless ($nodecount) {
    print "NO NODES FOUND\n";
}
```

This script allows you to chose between the XML::LibXML parser and the XML::XPath parser. It also allows you to define an xmlns attribute on the MyContainer element or leave it off depending on the arguments passed.

The xpath expression I'm using is "RootElement/MyContainer". When I run the query using the XML::LibXML parser without the namespace it finds the node with no problem:

```
benb@enkidu:~$ ROC/ECG/libxml_xpath.pl 'RootElement/MyContainer' libxml
--NODE 1--
<MyContainer>
    <MyField>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </MyField>
    <MyField>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>Ben</Value>
    </MyField>
  </MyContainer>
```

However, when I run it with the namespace in place it finds no nodes:

```
benb@enkidu:~$ ROC/ECG/libxml_xpath.pl 'RootElement/MyContainer' libxml use_namespace
NO NODES FOUND
```

Contrast this with the output when using the XMLL::XPath parser:

```
benb@enkidu:~$ ROC/ECG/libxml_xpath.pl 'RootElement/MyContainer' 0 # no namespace
--NODE 1--
<MyContainer>
    <MyField>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </MyField>
    <MyField>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>Ben</Value>
    </MyField>
  </MyContainer>
benb@enkidu:~$ ROC/ECG/libxml_xpath.pl 'RootElement/MyContainer' 0 1 # with namespace
--NODE 1--
<MyContainer xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
    <MyField>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </MyField>
    <MyField>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>Ben</Value>
    </MyField>
  </MyContainer>
```

Which of these parser implementations is doing it "right"? Why does XML::LibXML treat it differently when I use a namespace? What can I do to retrieve the node when the namespace is in place?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and for two possible solutions.

Comment: @ikegami, So has to be useful both to advanced *and* novice users. They shouldn't be discouraged to ask questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This is a FAQ. XPath considers any unprefixed name in an expression to belong to "no namespace".**

Then, the expression:

```
RootElement/MyContainer
```

selects all `MyContainer` elements that belong to "no namespace" and are children of all `RootElement` elements that belong to "no namespace" and are children of the context (current node). However, there are no elements at all in the whole document that belong to "no namespace" -- all elements belong to the default namespace.

This explains the result you are getting.  XML::LibXML *is* right.

**The common solution** is that the API of the hosting language allows a specific prefix to be bound to the namespace by "registering" a namespace. Then one can use an expression like:

```
x:RootElement/x:MyContainer
```

where `x` is the prefix with which the namespace has been registered.

**In the very rare occasions where the hosting language doesn't offer registering namespaces**, use the following expression:

```
*[name()='RootElement']/*[name()='MyContainer']
```

Comment: With XML::LibXML, you register namespaces using XML::LibXML::XPathContext. This is documented in `findnodes`.

Comment: @ikegami, One shouldn't know how all possible XPath hosts implement registering of namespace prefixes. The correct answer to this general and re-occurring question (if we want the answer to serve not only users of a particular XPath implementation) should explain what is happening and allow the users to look in their particular documentation for the implementation-defined details.

Comment: That may be, but the OP asked about how to do it in XML::LibXML, so why are you taking offense at me telling him the little bit you missed from your answer?

Comment: @ikegami, No offense taken. Just explaining to you the rationale for providing important *generally-useful* answer vs. a limited and more precise answer, directed only to the original asker. In case your original comment was targeting the asker, you could comment his question -- not this particular answer, where he may not see it.

Comment: I never suggested you should replace your answer with anything limited. It's directed to the OP, but it's a missing bit of your answer, which is is why it's posted as a reply to you answer. (Already mentioned this...)

Answer (score 7):

@Dmitre is right. You need to take a look at [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod) which will allow you to declare the namespace and then you can use namespace aware XPath statements. I gave an example of using this some time ago on stackoverflow - have a look at [Why should I use XPathContext with Perl's XML::LibXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673370/why-should-i-use-xpathcontext-with-perls-xmllibxml/2673452#2673452)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the XPathContext question. I suspected it could help me and attempted to use it without knowing what I was doing without any success. I'll see if the examples there will help.

Answer (score 1):

Using XML::LibXML 1.69.

Maybe this a XML::LibXML 1.69 thing but the strange part is that I can use the normal XPath and findnodes() and the code below prints the  nodes.

```
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<END_XML;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<RootElement>
   <MyContainer xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
    <MyField>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </MyField>
    <MyField>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>Ben</Value>
    </MyField>
  </MyContainer>
</RootElement>
END_XML

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

$parser->recover_silently(1);

my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);

my $root = $doc->documentElement();

foreach my $node ($root->findnodes('MyContainer/MyField')) {
     print $node->toString();
}
```

But if I change the namespace to something other than "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", then using XML::LibXML::XPathContext is required to get the same  nodes to print.

```
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<END_XML;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<RootElement>
  <MyContainer xmlns="http://something.org/2000/something/">
    <MyField>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </MyField>
    <MyField>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>Ben</Value>
    </MyField>
  </MyContainer>
</RootElement>
END_XML

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

$parser->recover_silently(1);

my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);

my $root = $doc->documentElement();

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($root);

$xpc->registerNs("x", "http://something.org/2000/something/");

foreach my $node ($xpc->findnodes('x:MyContainer/x:MyField')) {
    print $node->toString();
}
```

Comment: Remove the line `$parser->recover_silently(1);` in the first example and you'll get the error message `namespace error : reuse of the xmlns namespace name is forbidden`. If you use the `recover` option, the namespace declaration will simply be ignored. If you use `recover_silently` not even an error message will be printed. That's why it's usually a bad idea.