# Doing XPath using Perl

Tags: perl, xpath

I am coding with Perl on a Window 7 machine. I am able to extract data from the XML using the XPath code below

```
use strict;
use warning;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
        my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($newfile);
        my $query  = "/tradenet/message/header/unique_ref_no/date/text( )";
        my($node)   = $doc->findnodes($query);
        $node->setData("$file_seq_number");
```

However, when i use the same code on a different XML, the xpath from the second document looks as below:

```
/TradenetResponse/OutboundMessage/out:OutwardPermit/out:Declaration/out:Header/cac:UniqueReferenceNumber/cbc:SequenceNumeric
```

Together with the Perl code, this is what the extraction code looks like:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
    my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($newfile);
    my $query  = "/TradenetResponse/OutboundMessage/out:OutwardPermit/out:Declaration/out:Header/cac:UniqueReferenceNumber/cbc:SequenceNumeric/text( )";
    my($node)   = $doc->findnodes($query);
    $node->setData("$file_seq_number");
```

Using the second code, I am unable to retrieve the data from the second XML. I receive this error "Can't call method "setData"on an undefined value at Perl.pl line 5".

Does the ":" character in the second XPATH address affecting the code?

Comment: use strict; use warnings; should be at the top of your script.

Comment: hi, yes i do use strict and warnings, its actually at the top of the code chunk, however, it would be a lil long to post the whole thing here. Thanks for the advise and appreciate it much.

Comment: However, in light of the advise, I have added it to the code above... thanks!

Comment: You have to provide namespace for 'unnamed' elements as well, I suppose. Check [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4083929/1229023) for more details - and look for others, it's actually quite a popular sort of questions. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define what `out`, `cac`, and `cbc` mean in order for the XPath query to find the appropriate nodes:

```
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($newfile);
my $xpath_context = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc->documentElement());

# These URIs need to be the same as the ones in the source document
$xpath_context->registerNs('out', 'http://example.com/out.xsd');
$xpath_context->registerNs('cac', 'http://example.com/cac.xsd');
$xpath_context->registerNs('cbc', 'http://example.com/cbc.xsd');

my $query  = "/TradenetResponse/OutboundMessage/out:OutwardPermit/out:Declaration/out:Header/cac:UniqueReferenceNumber/cbc:SequenceNumeric/text( )";
my ($node) = $xpath_context->findnodes($query);
```

As promised, here is a working example.  First, the test input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- input.xml -->

<TradenetResponse xmlns:a="http://example.com/out.xsd"
                  xmlns:b="http://example.com/cac.xsd"
                  xmlns:c="http://example.com/cbc.xsd">
  <OutboundMessage>
    <a:OutwardPermit>
      <a:Declaration>
        <a:Header>
          <b:UniqueReferenceNumber>
            <c:SequenceNumeric>1234</c:SequenceNumeric>
          </b:UniqueReferenceNumber>
        </a:Header>
      </a:Declaration>
    </a:OutwardPermit>
  </OutboundMessage>
</TradenetResponse>
```

And here is the working Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# parse.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

my $newfile = "input.xml";
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($newfile);
my $xpath_context = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc->documentElement());

# These URIs need to be the same as the ones in the source document
$xpath_context->registerNs('out', 'http://example.com/out.xsd');
$xpath_context->registerNs('cac', 'http://example.com/cac.xsd');
$xpath_context->registerNs('cbc', 'http://example.com/cbc.xsd');

# Query wrapped for clarity                                                                                                         
my $query = "/TradenetResponse/OutboundMessage/out:OutwardPermit" .
            "/out:Declaration/out:Header/cac:UniqueReferenceNumber" .
            "/cbc:SequenceNumeric/text()";

my ($node) = $xpath_context->findnodes($query);

print "Value: " . $node->getData() . "\n";
```

The output for me is:

```
sean@localhost:~xmltest$ ./parse.pl
Value: 1234
```

Comment: Hello Sean, I tried the code above, changing the fake path with the actual XSD located on the localdrive but still getting the same error. will just keep trying.. thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: You marked this as the answer.  Were you able to make it work?  If not, I can try to come up with a working sample for you.

Comment: Hi Sean, I marked it by accident. My apologies. I would appreciate it if you would be able to come up with a working sample. Been wrecking my head almost for two days... I will uncheck it now. Thanks!

Comment: Sean... Trying it now... Thank you so much... really really appreciate this.