# Why is this xmlns attribute messing up my xpath query?

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-namespaces, libxml2

I'm parsing a simple jhove output using LibXML. However, I don't get the values I expect. Here's the code:

```
use feature "say";
use XML::LibXML;

my $PRSR = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xs=<DATA>; 
say $xs;
my $t1 = $PRSR->load_xml(string => $xs);
say "1:" . $t1->findvalue('//date');
$xs=<DATA>; 
say $xs;
$t1 = $PRSR->load_xml(string => $xs);
say "2:" . $t1->findvalue('//date');


__DATA__
<jhove xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/xml/ns/jhove" xsi:schemaLocation="http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/xml/ns/jhove http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/xml/xsd/jhove/1.3/jhove.xsd" name="Jhove" release="1.0 (beta 3)" date="2005-02-04"><date>2006-10-06T09:11:34+02:00</date></jhove>
<jhove><date>2006-10-06T09:11:34+02:00</date></jhove>
```

As you can see, the line "1:" is returning an empty string, while "2:" is returning the expected date. What is in the jhove-root-element that keeps the xpath query from working properly? I even tried in XML-Spy and there it works, even with the full header.

Edit: When I remove the xmlns-attribute from the root element, the xpath query works. But how is that possible?

Comment: It may be due to the default namespace declaration (`xmlns="http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/xml/ns/jhove"`) in your first inline XML snippet. Quite a few libraries require a specfic setup for this case. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673370/why-should-i-use-xpathcontext-with-perls-xmllibxml

Comment: You may be right. It's just that I did 100s of xpath querys in documents using namespaces without ever using an XPathContext, and never had a problem with that. Why here?

Comment: I know now why here: because the namespace is declared without a prefix and therefore cannot be simply added to the element name like in "jhove:date". An "invisible" namespace must either be declared or one can use *[local-name()="..."] .

Answer (score 5):

The [XML::LibXML::Node](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0117/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) documentation specifically mentions this issue and how to deal with it...

> *NOTE ON NAMESPACES AND XPATH:*
>
> A common mistake about XPath is to assume that node tests consisting of an element name with no prefix match elements in the default namespace. This assumption is wrong - by XPath specification, such node tests can only match elements that are in no (i.e. null) namespace.
>
> So, for example, one cannot match the root element of an XHTML document with `$node->find('/html')` since `'/html'` would only match if the root element `<html>` had no namespace, but all XHTML elements belong to the namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. (Note that `xmlns="..."` namespace declarations can also be specified in a DTD, which makes the situation even worse, since the XML document looks as if there was no default namespace).
>
> There are several possible ways to deal with namespaces in XPath:
>
> - The recommended way is to use the XML::LibXML::XPathContext module to define an explicit context for XPath evaluation, in which a document independent prefix-to-namespace mapping can be defined. For example:
>
>   ```
>   my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new;
>   $xpc->registerNs('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
>   $xpc->find('/x:html',$node);
>   ```
> - Another possibility is to use prefixes declared in the queried document (if known). If the document declares a prefix for the namespace in question (and the context node is in the scope of the declaration), XML::LibXML allows you to use the prefix in the XPath expression, e.g.:
>
>   ```
>   $node->find('/x:html');
>   ```

Comment: Thx, I figured that out by now also... since the document does not use prefixes, I assumed I don't need to deal with the namespace. I found another solution by using [local-name()="date"] instead of the element name itself... works for me and saves some hassle. You might want to include that in your answer, because otherwise your answer is very good.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution. Simply using this

```
say "1:" . $t1->findvalue('//*[local-name()="date"]');
```

will also find the value and save the hassle of declaring namespaces in an XPathContext. But apart from that, tobyinks answer is the correct one.

Comment: Useful to know, thank you for posting it!  Just like the question :)

Comment: Yes, apart from the missing closing bracket that I now added this is a really nice shortcut!